# How to implement search with recent results?

Tags: flutter, dart

Need help. I need to make a page with a search. Clicking on the TextField redirects me to the search page, which displays the latest search results. When entering text, you need to immediately display the data that matches the search. Prompt, how it can be implemented without use of SearchDelegate? If possible, then without using third-party packages.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) package?

it enables you to show some suggestions on typing, you can check the example in the readme tab for more info